# Is there an option in .NET MAUI to make only the top side of a border transparent?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, maui

I'm working on a .NET MAUI project and I need to make only the top side of a border transparent, while keeping the other sides visible. I've looked through the documentation but couldn't find a specific option for this scenario. Is there a built-in way or a recommended approach to achieve this in .NET MAUI?

Thanks in advance for any insights or suggestions!

Comment: I mean i could give you a hack way to do it

Comment: Could you give a schematic diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below with a bit of padding should work

```
<ContentView Padding="2,0,2,2" BackgroundColor="Black">
  <Border BackgroundColor="White"
          StrokeShape="Rectangle"
          StrokeThickness="0">
           <Entry/>
  </Border>
 </ContentView>
```

Padding with BackgroundColor changes imitates a border basically